# Unable to flash cc2650 from ubuntu machine

Tags: ubuntu, bluetooth-lowenergy, contiki

Timeout error is displayed on flashing cc2650, perfomed following steps:

1. Connected the cc2650 mote wih ubuntu machine
2. Compiled the client example for the target using following command:

```
make TARGET=srf06-cc26xx BOARD=launchpad/cc2650 savetarget
```

3. Tried to flashed the cc2650 module with following command:

```
sudo make PORT=/dev/ttyACM0 BOARD=launchpad/cc2650 client.upload
```

```html
sudo make PORT=/dev/ttyACM0 BOARD=launchpad/cc2650 client.upload
[sudo] password for subhanshu: 
using saved target 'srf06-cc26xx'
  CC        ../../../cpu/cc26xx-cc13xx/lib/cc26xxware/startup_files/ccfg.c
  CC        ../../../platform/srf06-cc26xx/launchpad/launchpad-sensors.c
  CC        ../../../platform/srf06-cc26xx/common/ext-flash.c
  CC        ../../../platform/srf06-cc26xx/common/board-spi.c
  CC        ../../../cpu/cc26xx-cc13xx/./ieee-addr.c
  AR        contiki-srf06-cc26xx.a
  CC        ../../../cpu/cc26xx-cc13xx/./fault-handlers.c
  CC        ../../../cpu/cc26xx-cc13xx/lib/cc26xxware/startup_files/startup_gcc.c
  CC        client.c
  LD        client.elf
arm-none-eabi-objcopy -O binary --gap-fill 0xff client.elf client.bin
python ../../../tools/cc2538-bsl/cc2538-bsl.py -e -w -v -p /dev/ttyACM0 client.bin
Opening port /dev/ttyACM0, baud 500000
Reading data from client.bin
Cannot auto-detect firmware filetype: Assuming .bin
Connecting to target...
ERROR: Timeout waiting for ACK/NACK after 'Synch (0x55 0x55)'
../../../cpu/cc26xx-cc13xx/Makefile.cc26xx-cc13xx:152: recipe for target 'client.upload' failed
make: *** [client.upload] Error 1
```

Comment: Don't use `sudo` to compile things. Add your user to the dialout group instead to get permissions to write to serial ports without root access.

Answer (score 0):

To successfully flash via the `.upload` target, the board needs to be in the bootloader mode.

To enter the bootloader mode on a TI Launchpad, do this:

1. connect the board to a host computer via USB cable
2. press and hold the left user button
3. press and release the reset button
4. release the left user button.

When this is done, running `make client.upload` on the host will reflash the board.

More specifically, the bootloader mode needs to be enabled config of the firmware and the bootloader pin needs to be in the right level during the reset of the board. `CCXXWARE_CONF_BL_LEVEL` and `CCXXWARE_CONF_BL_PIN_NUMBER` are the relevant defines here (the level and the pin number, respectively). In Contiki and Contiki-NG the bootloader mode is enabled by default, and TI Launchpads it's mapped to the left user button.

Alternative ways of flashing the firmware can be possible, for example via JTAG, using the [Uniflash](http://www.ti.com/tool/UNIFLASH) application provided by Texas Instruments.

Comment: Please have a look to my answer

Comment: I have tried with your mentioned steps and this time some piece of code was written in the mote but a different timeout error message is displayed. I have added a new question for the same, please refer to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57559020/timeout-error-is-displayed-on-uploading-code-to-ti-cc2650